# Mathematics of the star-mesh transformation

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, mathematics, topology, graph-theory

I'm trying to understand the [star-mesh transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star-mesh_transform) from a mathematical perspective. This transformation removes a node and by definition, the topology of the network changes, but the resulting network is equivalent.

My question is: what exactly happens to the network topology — in other words, what happens to the connections? So, what can we say about the star-mesh transform mathematically? For example, how does it differ from making a [topological tube map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tube_map) by stretching and bending the lines but preserving the connections?